# I want to show a particular image when it is clicked

Tags: jquery

I am developing a web template. There is gallery page in my webpage. I want to show that particular image on a special div when i clicked on an image. I have listed all images in `<a href="source of the image"></a>`

This is my code, please help me

```
<div class="p_set"  id="object">
<table name="portfolios_view" id="table_portfolio" class="posrtfolio_table_class" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
<tr>
<td>
<a href="" style="text-decoration:none;"> <div id="p_box"><img src="images/portfolio_tumb/1.jpg"></img> <p style="color:#000;font-size:1em; font-family:sans-serif;"> January 2016 <br>A moment 

</p></div></a></td>


<td>
<a href="" style="text-decoration:none;">
<div id="p_box">
<img src="images/portfolio_tumb/2.jpg"></img>
<p style="color:#000;font-size:1em; font-family:sans-serif;"> February 2016 <br>Black time 
</p></div></a></td>

<td> 
<a href="" style="text-decoration:none;"> <div id="p_box"><img src="images/portfolio_tumb/3.jpg"></img><p style="color:#000;font-size:1em; font-family:sans-serif;"> January 2016 <br>Tied Up 

</p></div></a></td>
<td> 
<a href="" style="text-decoration:none;"> <div id="p_box"><img src="images/portfolio_tumb/1.jpg"></img><p style="color:#000;font-size:1em; font-family:sans-serif;"> January 2016 <br>Tied Up 
</p></div></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way to show that particular image without using any database?
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Jquery solution would be like this

```
  $("img").click(function() {

    var img = $(this).clone();
    $("#image_viewer").html(img);
    $("#image_viewer").show();
  });
```

make the div to your desired width using css

```
#image_viewer{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

EDIT:updated fiddle
JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qnhdofyf/3/

Comment: i want to show it on this div <div class="image_viewer"></div>
its visibility mode is hidden, when any image clicked, visible the div and show the image on that div.. Please help me

Comment: it is not working, when i clicked on that image, the page is reloading,

Comment: Umm wh ydo you use a href ="" . jus remove that and it should work fine. the images are loaded using img src ="src to image" (Check the JSfiddle out)

Comment: Thanks...
Its worked..
Can you give me the code to show that image in 100% width and 100% height, also i want to see all images as slides on the div #image_viewer

Comment: the picture has only 300X200 px. when it is clicked i want to show 1312X543px pciture. I have saved the 1312X543 pictures in one folder